# top position absolute different with same parent div between mac and windows FF/Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser

I've read different people with other solutions but neither answer my strange issue. As you can observe on [link](http://cepods.com) the green text (`#scroller`) is position absolute and has `top: 173px;` To see it aligned with the rest of the text I would need to place the top element to `top:167px`. So it has 6px difference. What can I do to solve this issue? going crazy...

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
            <ul id="scroller">
                <li>Sustainable</li>
                <li>Eye Catching</li>
                <li>Modern Design</li>
                <li>Retail &amp; Pop-Up</li>
                <li>Sports-themed</li>
                <li>Event Space</li>
                <li>Bar/Restaurant</li>
                <li>Urban Living</li>
            </ul>
            <q>
              <span class="q-line"><strong>CEPODS</strong> are <!-- Retail &amp; Pop-Up  --><span class="word-mask"></span> Environments.</span>
              <span class="q-line">We repurpose Shipping Containers.</span>
              <span class="q-line lower"><strong>CEPODS</strong></span>
              <span class="q-line lower">...Container Evolution<span class="registered">®</span></span>
            </q>
<header>
    <nav>
        <a href="index.php">
            <h1 class="sprites-logo-cepods ir">cepods</h1>
        </a>
        <ul class="main-nav">
            <li>
                <a href="about.php">about</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="how-we-work.php">how we work</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropli">
                <a href="design.php">design<i class="icon-right-open-gal"></i></a>
                <ul class="sub-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="design-bar.php">bar</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="design-retail-space.php">retail space</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="design-restaurant.php">restaurant</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="design-event-service.php">event service</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="design-living.php">living</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="design-custom.php">custom</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="news.php">news</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="faq.php">faq</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
</div><!-- End wrapper -->
```

CSS:

```
#scroller {
    height: 50px;
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 173px;
    left: 207px;
    z-index: 1;
    font-family: helvetica-neue, helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 34px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);

    @media #{$ipad-l}{
      left: 220px;
    }

    @media #{$ipad-p}{
      left: 150px;
      top: 175px;
      height: 25px;
      font-size: 22px;
    }

    li{
      height: 50px;
      text-align: center;
      width: 305px;
      color:#08E700;

        @media #{$ipad-p}{
            width: 210px;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not put it inline with the `<p>` that is currently there?

Comment: @Vector Do you mean changing the span element to a p element will make the trick? Do not understand too well what you mean.

Comment: @Vector Did you mean to insert the ul#scroller inside the first span as an inline block?

Answer (score 0):

Just 2 css things to fix.

```
#scroller li {
  color: #08E700;
  height: 41px; /*  <-- this height was not right, (previous 50) should be same has background line height */
  text-align: center;
  width: 305px;
}

#scroller {
  font-family: helvetica-neue,helvetica,sans-serif;
  font-size: 34px;
  height: 41px;  /*  <-- this height was not right, (previous 50) should be same has background line height */
  left: 207px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  top: 167px;  /* <-- this was : 173px */
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry to say I've tried your changed but there was no effect. Also if this worked it should work for mac and for windows. Even so, I want to understand what you mean with should be the same as  background line-height? I dont't understand what you mean there with background line-height. Could you explain?